# accuracy of the mean

Tags: mean, standard-deviation

I am doing a study on the performance of Aquifer thermal energy storage systems. During this study, I get results with consist of a normal distribution around a mean. What can I now say about the accuracy of my mean? is there a statistical method for this? Take in mind that the result is dependent on multiple variables that explain the spread.

I first looked at a standard deviation but this results in use error margins. I think it is more accurate as it is known that the measurement devices have an accuracy of about 2 degrees centigrade.[image: One of my results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a single number statistic that summarizes the variability of the mean, then you are talking about [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error), i.e. standard deviation divided by the square root of sample size.

$$
{\sigma}_\bar{x}\ = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}
$$

If needed, you can calculate [confidence intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Assumptions_and_usage) for mean using it.